# ASP.NET application shows previous date than stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, date, jqgrid

My web application is built in ASP.NET MVC 5 with backend MySQL. Both application and database deployed on same web server.

The issue is that the date in grid (jqGrid) is shown one day before the date that is saved in database, i.e. if the MySQL database has a column that has 15-May-2015 then the jqGrid shows 14-May-2015.

This issue is only when the application is deployed on server. The application works perfectly when working in development environment on local machine.

I have noticed the time is also stored along with date, and if the time part is 00:00:00 then the grid output is previous day. Server location is Australia

Comment: How are you storing the date? Are you storing the time in UTC and converting it to Local Time? Is your application the one the stores the date?

Comment: An input form created in asp.net stores the date into MySQL database without any processing or conversion. The date is stored correctly. if I enter 15-May-2015 in the form, the same value is saved in db. But when displayed in grid, it shows 14-May-2015.

Comment: When you query the data for the grid do you receive a correct value? I mean in the controller just before returning it to the view

Comment: When debugging on local machine the result is fine.

Comment: I have noticed the time is also stored along with date, and if the time part is 00:00:00 then the grid output is previous day. Server location is Australia

Comment: You should include the exact column definition from `colModel` which you use. It's very important to know which fork of jqGrid you use and in which version. You should additionally use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace HTTP traffic and to include exact values which will be used as the input for dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by using the function ToLocalTime() for the date column in my ASP.NET MVC resultset.